# Regression Dataset Gap in Values

Tags: regression

How to you adress the problem if you want to train a regression where you have a big gap between the datapoints?

Can you group them somehow in Python?

Thank you.

Kidn regards

[image]

Comment: are you talking about linear or logistic regression?

Comment: Multiple Linear regression

Comment: Hello @ShuFFle2207. I think you just accidentally [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25121632) someone's answer instead of writing a comment or another question, so I've voted to reject your edit.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to use a simple equation with few parameters - as few as practical - where the fitted equation can only smoothly follow the shape of the data. I have extracted data from the scatterplot to make an example, however the numbers on the plot are very large which gives either very large or very small fitted parameter values in this example. Here is a simple exponential equation, "y = a * exp(bx)", with fitted parameters a =  1.3326440758146755E+06 and b =  1.7689425357488880E-06. I personally would re-scale the data by dividing the numbers by 1,000 or 1,000,000 to change the units.

[image: plot]